# Infinite Loop Not Infinite - Pyinstaller executable

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the code below on a Windows Server instance which doesnt allow me to install Python. I've created an exe using pyinstaller. The code runs but instead of staying in the infinite loop the terminal closes and stops running after the code has been executed once.

Can anyone shed some light please?

```
    import shutil
    import time
    import datetime

    backup_time = int(input('Enter the backup time interval in minutes: ')) * 60

    while True:
        shutil.copytree("src", "dstn" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S"))
        print ('I have made a backup of the rotas ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(backup_time)
```

Comment: Is the code getting an error maybe? What if you launch the exe via the command prompt? You might see an error outputted in that case, since otherwise it might be appearing right before the terminal window closes.

Comment: The code seems to run fine when it's opened through IDLE, it loops as it should.

Comment: I mean, specifically run the exe via the command prompt, not run the .py file it via IDLE. Like, open the start menu, type "cmd", click Command Prompt, then type in the path of the .exe and it'll run without closing the prompt after.

Comment: Thank you, I will remeber this for future reference. I have recreated the .exe and now it's working as it should on the server instance. I have no idea why it wasn't working in the first place.